# Vignetting on my Nikon D780 with AF-S 24-120mm f/4 G ED VR Lens

Tags: nikon, dslr, vignetting

I've recently got a new camera, the Nikon D780 with kit lens (AF-S 24-120mm f/4 G ED VR), the lens works great except for the vignetting I often get with. I have tried using it with and without the lens hood but it does not seem to change the result. I would be really grateful for some help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - could you please post some images showing the problem along with the exposure settings (shutter speed, aperture and ISO) for each? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lens seems to [suffer from vignetting](https://www.dxomark.com/dxomark-review-for-the-nikon-24-120-the-new-constant-f-4-aperture-on-dxomark/). The linked review gives you combinations of focal length/aperture that mitigate this.

On the other hand vignetting is quite easy to compensate in any photo editor/demosaïcing application worth its salt, and that lens is probably very widely supported.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I wasn't sure if it was something I was doing wrong! The review you've attached is very useful.

Comment: Good. Then please consider marking the answer as accepted (click on the checkmark under the votes). This helps others.